# Energy harvesting circuit modification

Tags: voltage, energy-harvesting

I'm currently doing a project on micro-power harvesting and I wanted to make some practical application but need to modify a circuit I've found. I'm not really sure about all the calculations, so I'd appreciate some help. Here's the circuit:

[image: vibrational energy harvesting circuit]

What I need is voltage output of 5 volts. What other modifications should I make in order to get the circuit work with this constant output of 5V?

Answer (score 1):

The circuit shown using the [MAX1675](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1674-MAX1676.pdf) is a boost regulator producing 3.3V and if you look at the data sheet, it is capable of being modified to produce up to 5.5V. Page 6 says that if the FB pin is grounded, the output will be 5V.

This is dependent on sufficient voltage from the piezo device and loading conditions on the output being reasonable and compatible with the energy you can take from the piezo.